Uncaught Error: There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary.. NEXT JS
Currently working with NEXT JS as show package.json below


{
  "name": "mass_fe",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "build:production": "npm run build && npm run start",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@amcharts/amcharts5": "^5.6.2",
    "@ant-design/cssinjs": "^1.17.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "@types/node": "20.5.9",
    "@types/react": "18.2.21",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.7",
    "antd": "^5.11.1",
    "antd-img-crop": "^4.21.0",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.15",
    "axios": "^1.5.1",
    "clsx": "^2.0.0",
    "cookies-next": "^4.2.1",
    "crypto-js": "^4.2.0",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.10",
    "eslint": "8.48.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.19",
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "html2canvas": "^1.4.1",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^3.0.0",
    "immer": "^10.0.3",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "next": "13.4.19",
    "next-auth": "^4.23.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.11.0",
    "react-pdf": "^9.1.0",
    "react-quill": "^2.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.2",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "redux-saga": "^1.2.3",
    "sass": "^1.77.8",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.3",
    "tar": "^7.4.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.10",
    "typescript": "5.2.2",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5",
    "zustand": "^4.4.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/crypto-js": "^4.2.2",
    "@types/js-cookie": "^3.0.3"
  }
}



and load balancer nginx like this


    upstream nextjs_servers {
        # Server Next.js yang akan menangani permintaan
        server localhost:80;
        server localhost:90;
    }

    server {
        listen 100;
        server_name localhost;

        # Akses Next.js
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://nextjs_servers;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            
            # WebSocket support (optional, useful for hot reloading or real-time features)
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

            # Buffer settings
            proxy_buffer_size 2048k;
            proxy_buffers 6 1000k;
            proxy_busy_buffers_size 2048k;
            proxy_temp_file_write_size 2048k;

            # CORS & Security Headers (optional)
            add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
            add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
            add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;
        }
    }



when I build the 2 project(same project) from different port, and trying to access localhost:100(where I config the load balancer Nginx) always show application error.
I've try to npm run dev both port to see where's the error come from but find nothing, but when I build both port the error start to appear again. I've search every error similar, but the other is related to missplaced html.

Can you share the Nextjs code where you've added suspense?

@SharanBalakrishnan there's no suspense in my login page, cause the error appear when I try to access login page

I think you need to add a suspense boundary to your Next application. That will provide a fallback UI while there is an issue with the flow or until data is being fetched. Your application doesn't have a fallback to go to instead of crashing.

You need to have something like this in your project.
 const AppRouter = () => {
  return (
      <Suspense fallback={<Preloader />}>
        <Routes>
      </Suspense>


still crashing after add suspense
  return (     <html lang='en'>       <body>         <RootStyleRegistry>           <ConfigProvider componentSize='large' theme={theme} locale={locale}>             <NextAuthProvider sessions={sessions}>               <Suspense fallback={<p>Loading....</p>}>{children}</Suspense>             </NextAuthProvider>           </ConfigProvider>         </RootStyleRegistry>       </body>     </html>   ); }

Did you try adding the suspense as a parent to NextAuthProvider?
